# R How to subtract date from next date below and group by?

Tags: r

I have the following data (this is a sample, my dataset is quite large):

```
ID| Date        
A | 2010-12-30 
A | 2010-12-13 
A | 2010-08-23 
B | 2011-06-24 
B | 2011-06-13 
B | 2010-02-20
```

What I need to do is to calculate the difference between dates, based on the ID. The calculation must start from the first row and subtract the date on the row below.

So for the above data, the desired output would be the DateDiff column below:

```
ID| Date        | DateDiff
A | 2010-12-30  | 17       (which is 2010-12-30 - 2010-12-13) 
A | 2010-12-13  | 112      (which is 2010-12-13 - 2010-08-23) 
A | 2010-08-23  | 0        (this result should be 0 as the ID (A) does not match the ID below (B)   
B | 2011-06-24  | 11       (which is 2011-06-24 - 2011-06-13)
B | 2011-06-13  | 478      (which is 2011-06-13 - 2010-02-20)
B | 2010-02-20  | 0        (this result is 0 again as there is no ID in the next row thus the ID (B) does not match the ID below)
```

I have used the following code which is close to the desired result:

```
df$DateDiff <- ave(as.numeric(df$DATE), df$ID, FUN=function(x) c(0,abs(diff(x))))
```

However, it calculates by subtracting the second date from the first, and therefore entering in 0 in the first row, like so:

```
ID| Date        | DateDiff
A | 2010-12-30  | 0 (as there is no date above)       
A | 2010-12-13  | 17
A | 2010-08-23  | 112 (as it calculates the diff between the first date in ID (B) from the last in ID (A)  
B | 2011-06-24  | 0
B | 2011-06-13  | 11 
B | 2010-02-20  | 478
```

As you can see, the result is close but not quite there. I have searched long and hard but have not been able to locate a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like your code is perfect, EXCEPT in the function you've created it should be `c(abs(diff(x)),0)` instead. i.e. calculate the difference then put a 0 on the end.

Example:

```
ID <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
DATE <- as.Date(c("2010-12-30",
            "2010-12-13",
            "2010-08-23",
            "2011-06-2",
            "2011-06-13",
            "2010-02-20"
))
df <- data.frame(ID, DATE)

df$DateDiff <- ave(as.numeric(df$DATE), df$ID, FUN=function(x) c(abs(diff(x)),0))
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr::lead` to shift your `Date` by 1

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(DateDiff = abs(dplyr::lead(Date, 1, default=NA) - Date))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups: ID [2]
  # ID    Date       DateDiff
  # <chr> <date>     <time>  
# 1 A     2010-12-30 17      
# 2 A     2010-12-13 112     
# 3 A     2010-08-23 <NA>    
# 4 B     2011-06-24 11      
# 5 B     2011-06-13 478     
# 6 B     2010-02-20 <NA> 

df <- read.table(text="ID Date        
A 2010-12-30 
A 2010-12-13 
A 2010-08-23 
B 2011-06-24 
B 2011-06-13 
B 2010-02-20", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(lubridate)
df$Date <- ymd(df$Date)
```

Comment: He doesn't need to shift, he's already got the functionality for it, he's just put the 0 in the wrong place in his function :)

Comment: You should test if your solution works...anyways, I still think learning about `dplyr::lead/lag` is useful. (If you can show it works...I'll give you back the upvote, but I got an error...since OP got it to work, +1 again)

Comment: Thanks for that :) Since we posted at similar times I thought we may have crossed paths! I agree that lead/lag are useful functions when things are naturally off by one.

Comment: thank you so much. That is exactly what I need! Both solutions worked, but since I already have the function, I have amended to include LachlanO's solution (note it was missing a bracket at the end) - c(abs(diff(x)),0))

Comment: Thanks! I've edited it to put the bracket in as well, I've become far too accustomed to RStudio's auto-completes :) I've also put in the output for completeness. Clever little function by the way, you'd already done the hard part.

Comment: Actually, I've changed the bracket back. That extra bracket is only required because of the `ave` function, not because of your custom function :)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,.(Date,c(-diff(Date),0)),by=ID]
                   ID       Date       V2
1:                 A  2010-12-30  17 days
2:                 A  2010-12-13 112 days
3:                 A  2010-08-23   0 days
4:                 B  2011-06-24  11 days
5:                 B  2011-06-13 478 days
6:                 B  2010-02-20   0 days
```

Base R:

```
transform(data,A=unlist(by(Date,ID,FUN=function(x)c(-diff(x),0))))
                   ID       Date   A
1:                 A  2010-12-30  17
2:                 A  2010-12-13 112
3:                 A  2010-08-23   0
4:                 B  2011-06-24  11
5:                 B  2011-06-13 478
6:                 B  2010-02-20   0
```